# Sending notification does not work

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications

I'm writing an app having `minSdkVersion = 9` and `maxSdkVersion = 21`. In `service` I have written a code to send notification, user will be notified when pre-set time matches current time.

However, it notifies me perfectly if I run it in emulator having **API = 19** but if I run in my device having **API = 10** it does not notify me and crashes the app.

I'm using Android-Studio in Ubuntu, it doesn't provide device debugging feature. So I can't even see the `logcat`.

Here is my relevant code

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

// Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TRAlarmScreen.class);
//    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//    alarmIntent.putExtras(intent);
//    getApplication().startActivity(alarmIntent); */

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int id = extras.getInt("id");
    String title = extras.getString("title");
    String des = extras.getString("des");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setContentText(des);
    mBuilder.setTicker("New Message Alert!");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tr);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

What is the issue? Do I need to add any support library or something to make it work in lower API levels?

The error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.android.saathi id=1 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)

My `logcat` while running in device having api 10

```
02-27 02:27:41.812    4760-4760/com.android.saathi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.android.saathi.TRService@405a3bd0 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.android.saathi/.TRService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.android.saathi id=1 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2372)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1111)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.android.saathi id=1 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
        at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:394)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:111)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:91)
        at com.android.saathi.TRService.onStartCommand(TRService.java:42)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1111)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "it does not notify me and crashes the app" -- then look at the Java stack trace in LogCat. "I'm using Android-Studio in Ubuntu, it doesn't provide device debugging feature" -- **I** am using Android Studio in Ubuntu, and it most certainly **does** "provide device debugging feature".

Comment: Do you switch on developer options? Run your app on emulator and open Logcat view in your ide

Comment: @CommonsWare in `android sdk manager -> extras` category it shows `google usb driver` is `not compatible with linux`. So I can't run directly in device. And sir if ubuntu lets debug, would you please tell me how can I do so?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak yes, I run app in emulator, I am able to see log in logcat, but there's no error it shows. Even though I'm posting in my question. Wait a second.

Comment: You do not need drivers for OS X or Linux. Usually, you just enable debugging on the device in Developer Options, and plug the device into your Ubuntu machine, and it just works. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Comment: @user4583520 I see nothing in this log. When you have crash on your device, you get error on your logcat. I need it

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak see I again updated my logcat, it shows error now

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for suggestion, I can debug the device now. And check I have updated my logcat. It shows what causes app not work

Comment: @user4583520 Where do you call this notification ? In service ? Did you register your service in Manifest?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Yes, I call in service's `onStartCommand` method and I also have registered this service in `manifest` file, it works very well with api >= 11, but doesn't work with api <11.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak see I have added entire `onStartCommand` method in question

Comment: @user4583520 How you startService could you post part of this code. I tried to reproduce your issue but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setContentIntent()` on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`, to indicate what should happen when the user taps on the `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had that same Error.
you need to put a PendingIntent in the   `setContentIntent()` (like what the selected answer said)

in your case like this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
  mBuilder.setContentText(des);
  mBuilder.setTicker("New Message Alert!");
  mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tr);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```